# Xubuntu 12.04 network manager menu is displayed partially

Tags: network-manager, xubuntu, xfce

Installed Xubuntu 12.04 yesterday, all latest updates are installed.
When I login to my XFCE session and click on NetworkManager icon, very poor menu is shown:

[image: poor menu]

But if I disable networking by unchecking "Enable networking" menu item and then enable it again, I see a full menu:

[image: full menu]

How can I tell NetworkManager to show a full menu from the beginning?

Comment: Certainly a bug. Have you tried waiting a very long time to see if it eventually comes up by itself? I have a similar issue with gnome classic.

Comment: No I haven't. Strange, but it works fine today. So the issue is disappeared.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See bug report: https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/network-manager/+bug/983583